# Using Mockito and PowerMockito for DAO testing

Tags: java, mockito, dao, powermockito

I want to test my DAO methods using Mockito (and PowerMockito if needed), but I don't know how to do this. The biggest problem with calling static method (MySQLDAOFactory.getConnection() in MySQLStationDAO). Can you help me?

I obtain connection this way:

```
public class MySQLDAOFactory extends DAOFactory {     
        public static Connection getConnection() throws DAOException {
            Connection con = null;
            try {
                con = getDataSource().getConnection();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new DAOException(Messages.CANNOT_OBTAIN_CONNECTION, e);
            }
            return con;
        }
```

And here is a DAO method:

```
public class MySQLStationDAO implements StationDAO {
    @Override
    public List<Station> getAllStations() throws DAOException {
        List<Station> stations = new ArrayList<>();
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            con = MySQLDAOFactory.getConnection();
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(MySQLQueries.SQL_GET_ALL_STATIONS);
            while (rs.next()) {
                stations.add(extractStation(rs));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DAOException(Messages.CANNOT_OBTAIN_ALL_STATIONS, e);
        } finally {
            MySQLDAOFactory.close(con, stmt, rs);
        }
        return stations;
    }
```

Comment: And what exactly is your problem? Do you get an exception?

Comment: We may also need some additional information.  Where is your DataSource being configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. JUnit: use `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` at the class-level.

   TestNG: make your test class extend [`PowerMockTestCase`](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.6.2/apidocs/org/powermock/modules/testng/PowerMockTestCase.html).
2. Use `@PrepareForTest(MySQLDAOFactory.class)` at the class-level in order to instruct PowerMock to prepare the `MySQLDAOFactory` class for testing.
3. Use `PowerMockito.mockStatic(MySQLDAOFactory.class)` in order to
   mock all methods of `MySQLDAOFactory` class.

   It is also possible to use [partial mocking](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage#partial-mocking):

   `PowerMockito.stub(PowerMockito.method(MySQLDAOFactory.class,        "getConnection")).toReturn(Mockito.mock(Connection.class));`
4. Use something similar in order to stub `getConnection()`:

   `Connection mockConnection = Mockito.mock(Connection.class);
   Mockito.when(MySQLDAOFactory.getConnection()).thenReturn(mockConnection);`
5. Execute `getAllStations()` on a **real instance** of `MySQLStationDAO`, since you are testing `MySQLStationDAO` class.
6. If you want to verify that `getConnection()` method has been called, use something similar:

   `PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
   MySQLDAOFactory.getConnection();`

   However, please read [Mockito.verify(T)](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verify(T)) javadoc for the reasons why it is recommended either to stub or to verify the invocation, not both.

In general, you may want to consult [Mockito docs](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html) and [PowerMockito docs](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage) for more information.

Full example that was created using JUnit 4.11, Mockito 1.9.5 and PowerMock (PowerMockito) 1.5.6 (please be careful with versions, since there is a lot of compatibility issues):

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MySQLDAOFactory.class)
public class MySQLDAOFactoryTest {

    private StationDAO stationDAO;

    @Mock
    private Connection mockConnection;

    @Mock
    private Statement mockStatement;

    @Mock
    private ResultSet mockResultSet;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        stationDAO = new MySQLStationDAO();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetAllStations_StatementCreated() throws DAOException, SQLException {
        // given
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(MySQLDAOFactory.class);
        Mockito.when(MySQLDAOFactory.getConnection()).thenReturn(mockConnection);
        Mockito.when(mockConnection.createStatement()).thenReturn(mockStatement);
        Mockito.when(mockStatement.executeQuery(anyString())).thenReturn(mockResultSet);

        // when
        stationDAO.getAllStations();

        // then
        Mockito.verify(mockConnection).createStatement();
    }
}
```

What is next? Check that `executeQuery()` method has been called with expected arguments? Test how `SQLException` is handled? These are reasonable scenarios for unit testing, but what about integration testing? I would recommend [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/howto.html) for this purpose. It puts your test database into a known state between test runs, and allows to verify a returned result against an expected XML dataset.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, your problem is when you are calling MySQLDAOFactory.getConnection(); In terms of testing you want to test your MySQLStationDAO class. This is your SUT (system under test). That means that you have to mock all the dependencies that your SUT has. In this case, the MySQLDAOFactory.

To do that you can use Mockito to easily mock that class and stub the methods that MySQLDAOFactory presents. One example would be

```
    package com.iseji.app.dao;

import junit.framework.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;    
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import java.sql.Connection;

import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestMySqlDaoFactory {

    MySqlDaoFactory mySqlDaoFactory;
    Connection connection;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws DAOException {
        mySqlDaoFactory = mock(MySqlDaoFactory.class);
        connection = mock(Connection.class);
    }

    @Test(expected = DAOException.class)
    public void testEmptyUrlGetsDaoException() throws DAOException {
        when(mySqlDaoFactory.getConnection(null)).thenThrow(new DAOException());
        mySqlDaoFactory.getConnection(null);
    }

    @Test
    public void testFullUrlGetsConnection() throws DAOException {
        when(mySqlDaoFactory.getConnection(anyString())).thenReturn(connection);
        Assert.assertEquals(mySqlDaoFactory.getConnection(anyString()), connection);
    }
}
```

As you can see you can specify the behaviour of you DaoFactory. That isolates your Dao class which is the class that you want to test.

Comment: Please note that `getConnection()` method is static. Your answer will work only for instance methods.

Comment: Oh yes. I didn't see that. Then Mockito is not enough as you cannot mock static methods. In such a case agree with the given asnwer